# angularJS Service injection into run block

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have an Angular (1.5) app with an authentication service (see below) I have created.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.core")
        .service("mfAuth", mfAuth);

    /** @ngInject */
    function mfAuth(api, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, $cookies) {

        var currentUser = { userName: "" };
        getSession();

        var setRememberMe = function (rememberme, userId) {
            if (rememberme && userId && userId > 0) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
                $cookies.put('remember_me', userId, { expires: date });
            } else
                $cookies.remove('remember_me');
        };

        function changeUser(user) {
            var userProps = {
                displayName: user.displayName,
                ...
            };
            angular.extend(currentUser, userProps);
        }

        function isLoggedIn(user) {
            if (user === undefined) {
                user = currentUser;
            }
            return user && user.userId > 0;
        };

        function getSession(force) {
            var rememberme = $cookies.get('remember_me') !== undefined;
            if (rememberme || force) {
                var apiAuth = new api.Auth();
                apiAuth.$getSession(
                    null,
                    function(response) {
                        if (response.result !== undefined) {
                            changeUser(response.result);
                            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.isAuthenticated);
                        } else {
                            changeUser({});
                            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
                        }
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        changeUser({});
                        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                changeUser({});
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
            }
        };

        function login(user, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            var apiAuth = new api.Auth();
            apiAuth.userName = user.userName;
            apiAuth.password = user.password;
            apiAuth.$login(
                null,
                function (response) {
                    getSession(true);
                    if (successCallback)
                        successCallback(response);
                    setRememberMe(user.rememberme, response.userId);
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (errorCallback)
                        errorCallback(response);
                }
            );
        };

        function logout(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            var apiAuth = new api.Auth();
            apiAuth.$logout(
                null,
                function (response) {
                    changeUser({});
                    if (successCallback)
                        successCallback();
                    setRememberMe(false, null);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.logoutSuccess);
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (errorCallback)
                        errorCallback(response);
                }
            );
        }

        return {
            isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
            login: login,
            logout: logout,
            user: currentUser
        };
    }
}());
```

I am listening to the broadcasts on my main runBlock like so...

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .run(runBlock);

    /** @ngInject */
    function runBlock(msUtils, fuseGenerator, fuseConfig, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function (ev, reason) {
            if (!$state.is('app.auth_login')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('app.auth_login');
            }
        });
        $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.isAuthenticated, function (ev, reason) {
            if ($state.is('app.auth_login')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('app.dashboard');
            }
        });
        $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.logoutSuccess, function (ev, reason) {
            if (!$state.is('app.auth_login')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('app.auth_login');
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

When the service is injected into a login controller everything works as expected - the service is instantiated and the getSession() function fires and the app determines if the user requires authentication or not.

My issue is that I need to be able to access the service from the run block for some authorisation features and the moment I inject the mfAuth service into my runBlock function I find that the AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated is detected correctly but the $state.go method doesn't work and the user is not redirected to the login state.

I've been reading around and cannot find any hint as to the problem.  I've tried listening for ui-router's $stateChangeError event and it isn't firing.  I'm out of ideas so thought I'd turn to stack overflow.  I've tried finding similar questions on stack overflow and I'm sure the answer will be here already but am struggling getting the correct keywords to find the problem.

Anyone able to help?

UPDATE
I've just added the following logging on $stateChangeStart...

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("event: ", event);
        console.log("toState: ", toState);
        console.log("toParams: ", toParams);
        console.log("fromState: ", fromState);
        console.log("fromParams: ", fromParams);
    });
```

This produces the following console output

```
event:  Object {name: "$stateChangeStart", targetScope: Scope, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: Scope} core.run.js:63
toState:  Object {url: "/auth/login", views: Object, bodyClass: "login", name: "app.auth_login"} core.run.js:64
toParams:  Object {} core.run.js:65
fromState:  Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true} core.run.js:66
fromParams:  Object {} core.run.js:62
event:  Object {name: "$stateChangeStart", targetScope: Scope, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: Scope} core.run.js:63
toState:  Object {url: "/dashboard", views: Object, resolve: Object, name: "app.dashboard"} core.run.js:64
toParams:  Object {} core.run.js:65
fromState:  Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true} core.run.js:66
fromParams:  Object {}
```

So the problem is that the service's getSession is firing and requesting navigation to the login state BEFORE anything else such as ($urlRouterProvider.otherwise and the url entered in to the browser's address bar)..

Comment: can you try removing event.preventDefault(); and check whether $state.go('app.auth_login'); is getting called?

Comment: @Thalaivar I should have said that I used breakpoints to determine the $state.go method is getting called and it is - the problem is that another state is being called afterwards (q updated)

Comment: Does this issue comes if using a lesser version of angular?

Comment: Any specific reason or version in mind?  Obviously dependency-wise that isn't such an easy thing to test so some direction would be appreciated...

Comment: I've just quick tried a couple and it introduces problems with the theme I'm using so rolling back into older versions isn't an option for me